# How can I properly add images using multer without getting errors?

Tags: express, postman, mern, multer, cloudinary

I am having issues with uploading images still, I get 200 when I upload my forms without attaching images but got no response when I attached Image.

I'm trying to upload image in MongoDB using multer and react but I'm unable to post it. I have three inputs in by form i.e title, description and image. If I try to post title and content only it is successfully being posted.

Here is my code:

```
const postSchema = new Schema(
  {
    title: { type: String, required: true, trim: true },
    description: { type: String, required: true, trim: true },
    image: {
      type: Object,
    },
```

My file upload config:

```
import { v2 as cloudinary } from "cloudinary";
import { CloudinaryStorage } from "multer-storage-cloudinary";
 
cloudinary.config({
  cloud_name: process.env.CLOUDINARY_CLOUD_NAME,
  api_key: process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_KEY,
  api_secret: process.env.CLOUDINARY_SECRET_KEY,
});
 
const storage = new CloudinaryStorage({
  cloudinary,
  allowedFormats: ["jpg", "png", "jpeg"],
  params: {
    folder: "leo-blog",
    format: "jpg",
    transformation: [{ width: 500, height: 500, crop: "limit" }],
  },
});
 
export default storage;
```

My post route

```
import { Router } from "express";
import multer from "multer";
import postController from "../../controller/posts/postController.js";
import storage from "../../utilities/fileUpload.js";
 
const upload = multer({ storage });
const postRouter = Router();
 
postRouter
  .post("/posts/create", upload.single("image", {name:'image'}), postController.createPost)
  .get("/posts", postController.fetchAllPosts)
  .get("/posts/:postId", postController.fetchOnePost)
  .put("/posts/:postId", postController.updatePost)
  .delete("/posts/:postId", postController.deletePost);
 
export default postRouter;
```

My create post logic

```
    const postController = {
      createPost: handler(async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.file);
    try {
      const { description, title } = req.body;
 
      const postCreated = await Post.create({
        description,
        title,
        image: req?.file,
      });
 
      res.json(postCreated);
     } catch (error) {
      res
        .status(500)
        .json({ message: "Internal Server Error", error: error.message });
      }
    }),
 //Other logic
```

Here is what my postman looked like on every trial, I have also tried it from React and I got the same issue.

[image]

I  would appreciate if you can help point out my error, something like this has also kept me hanging on one of my projects.

[Here](https://github.com/emmypelo/mern_blog_30days) is the git

I should get the file object on submit but I got no response